# How can I return an array out of try-catch block in java?

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch

I created a 2D array from reading a file and I want to return this array. However I use try-catch block because of reading file. At this point I can't return this array from this function.Also when I try to write the elements of this array in try-catch block, it works but out of block it doesn't. What should I do to get the array?

My code is as below:

```
 public static double[][] readFile(String fileName)  {
     final double[][]data = new double[178][13];
      int x=0, y=0;
    try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
        String[]values=line.split(",");
        for(String str:values){
            double str_double=Double.parseDouble(str);
            data[x][y]=str_double;
            System.out.print(data[x][y]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    reader.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){}

     return data;

 }
```

Finally, with helps of everyone I found a solution. One of my mistake is defining y. Beacuse each line has 14 elements but I assigned it to 13. Also I changed assignment method of array. Maybe anyone needs, so I post it to here my solution:

```
public static double[][] readFile(String fileName)  {
      double[][]data=new double[178][14];
      int x=0, y;
    try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    String[]values;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){


        values=line.split(",");

       for(y=0; y<values.length; y++){
           data[x][y]=Double.parseDouble(values[y]);
       }
       x++;
    }



    reader.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Aborting due to error: " + e);}

     return data;

 }
```

Comment: Could you just return null from within your catch block (instead of the incomplete data array) to indicate that there was an error?

Comment: in try-catch block it works but out of the block I get all elements of array as 0.0. I do not get any error.

Comment: You always assign value to `data[0][0]`, since `x` and `y` are never updated.

Comment: You should be able to return "data" just fine, assuming your slightly wonky indentation is not confusing me.  If it's not returning it's due to not executing the code to set the values.

Comment: As PM77-1 says, you probably want to replase the line             "data[x][y]=str_double;" with "data[x++][y]=str_double;" and add y++ at the end of your loop to populate your array correctly.

Comment: `catch(Exception e){}` :'(

Comment: When you blow up in that code, the array is as good as dead to you.  You can't read from the file, or the format of the double you read was invalid; something along those lines.  Why do you need to get the value back?  Are you satisfied with a partially filled array?

Comment: Because I use that array for some computation.

Comment: As someone else said, x and y aren't changing, and that prevents the array from getting filled.

Comment: yes, I got my mistake but how can I correct it?

Comment: Try the new version of the code I just added. The old version may also work after correcting index counting, but it is still not generic enough.

Comment: I tried and it works. Thank you. Also, I checked your solution as correct answer. Thank you again.

Comment: As I discovered at some point, you can also upvote answers (not only mine, of course). Earlier on I gave you an upvote, since you are new here. It takes patience, but you will get there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code assigns only one value at the array, i.e. the element `data[0][0]`, since `x` and `y` never change from 0.

Assuming that `x` is the line and `y` is the column (element in the line), the following should work:

```
public static double[][] readFile(String fileName) {
     final double[][]data = new double[178][13];
      int x, y;
    try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    x = 0; // Reset the line counter
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // Read a new line
        y=0; // Reset the column counter, since this is a new line 
        String[]values=line.split(",");
        for(String str:values){
            double str_double=Double.parseDouble(str);
            data[x][y]=str_double;
            System.out.print(data[x][y]+" ");
            ++y; // Advance to the next column
        }
        ++x; // Advance to the next line
        System.out.println();
    }
    reader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Aborting due to error: " + e);
    }    
     return data;    
 }
```

The above assumes, of course, that no errors occur as a result of calling `readLine()` or `parseDouble()`. If any such error happens, or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs, the returned array will only contain the elements read thus far.

Here is an improved version, again maintaining as much of the original code as possible:

```
public static double[][] readFile(String fileName) {
    ArrayList<double[]> numbers = new ArrayList<double[]>();        

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // Read a new line             
            int y=0; // Reset the column counter, since this is a new line 

            String[] values = line.split(",");

            if (values.length > 0) {
                double[] elements = new double[values.length];

                for (String str:values) {
                    double str_double;
                    try {
                        str_double = Double.parseDouble(str);
                        elements[y] = str_double;
                        System.out.print(elements[y] + " ");
                        ++y; // Advance to the next column
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        continue; // Not a double, ignore
                    }
                }                   
                numbers.add(elements);                  
            } else {
                numbers.add(new double[0]); // No numbers read from the line
            }
            System.out.println();
        }                       
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Aborting due to error: " + e);
    }

    return numbers.toArray(new double[0][0]);
}
```

Neither of the two versions is tested, but they should both be close to a working solution.

The second approach is more generic and should be preferred, although, to avoid boxing/unboxing between `double` and `Double`, it assumes that, if any element read as a string is not a valid `double`, the corresponding position in the `elements` array will be filled by the next valid `double`, if any. So, if, for example, there are 10 elements in a line and only 8 of them are valid in total, then the first 8 positions of the array will contain the values of these elements and the last 2 positions will contain `0` (set during the initialization of the `elements` array).

Comment: I got it but this version of code is reading only the first line of the file.

Comment: Then you probably have an error in the parseDouble. Use the newer version with the print statement in the catch block.

Comment: No, I have no error. At the end of running code, it says build successfully.

Comment: You probably have a runtime error. Just copy the code and run it.

Comment: As I said before, I don't get any error although you don't believe to me.

Comment: Are you sure you have the System.out.println("Aborting due to error: " + e); statement in the code you run?

Comment: OK, you're right. It says: Aborting due to error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13

Comment: The code should also check for array index bounds. Also, there is no error handling in case you read something else than a double from the file. I will try putting together an improved version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific need for declaring the variable as a final variable.
You need not declare it as private as well.

simple

```
double[][]data = new double[178][13];
```

variable declaration is incorrect

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with declaring it final.  This might actually be a useful strategy in some cases, where one wanted to assure that the array did not get reassigned in a complex mess of code.  (Though normally it's just an unnecessary distraction.)

Comment: (It's unusual, to say the least, to use the "final" attribute on a local variable.)

Comment: The "final" modifier means that data will always point to the same array in memory. The elements (contents) of the array can be modified at any time.